# error : Action Delegate "Not all path return value"

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to call a function with single parameter. I want to call it through Action Delegate but getting error message "Not all code paths return a value".

I tried and I am able to do it with parameter-less function. I

```
{
 .... //Getting string from the selected item in ListBox.
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(displayText(myTextBlock.Text)));  
 }

private Action<string> displayText(string p)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(p);
    }
```

Could you please help me.

Comment: Your `displayText` method does not return an `Action<string>`.

Comment: All I am trying to do is to call a parametrized function with no return value. Using my above procedure I can only create object of Action or Func<T> delegate type and I chose Action because in my code I have no need to return value. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Thank you, I got your point.

Comment: Use simply `Action` instead of `Action<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

If `displayText` just shows a MessageBox it doesn't need to return anything:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => displayText(myTextBlock.Text)));

private void displayText(string p)
{
    MessageBox.Show(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of displayText indicates it takes a string and returns an Action.  The compiler is expecting you to return an Action in that function but all you do is show a message box.  Changing that return type to void would remove the compiler error, if all you intend to do is show the message box.

Comment: I have also tried changing my function type to Void but the compiler is showing error "Method name expected". All I am trying to do is to call a parametrized function with no return value. Using my above procedure I can only create object of Action or Func<T> delegate type and I chose Action because in my code I have no need to return value. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @user3571361 - did you really use `Void` (capital V) or was it `void` (lowercase v)? C# will only understand the lowercase version.